# Empty class object in Python

Tags: python, oop, empty-class

I'm teaching a Python class on object-oriented programming and as I'm brushing up on how to explain classes, I saw an empty class definition:

```
class Employee:
    pass
```

The example then goes on to define a name and other attributes for an object of this class:

```
john = Employee()
john.full_name = "john doe"
```

Interesting!

I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically define a function for an instance of a class like this? something like:

```
john.greet() = print 'Hello, World!'
```

This doesn't work in my Python interpreter, but is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Possible? Yes. A good idea? Rarely (outside of some metaprogramming, of course).

Comment: The shortest empty class definition I've seen is from http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/832915#832915: `Employee=type('Employee',(),{})` and then `john=Employee()` etc.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A class is more or less a fancy wrapper for a `dict` of attributes to objects. When you instantiate a class you can assign to its attributes, and those will be stored in `foo.__dict__`; likewise, you can look in `foo.__dict__` for any attributes you have already written.

This means you can do some neat dynamic things like:

```
class Employee: pass
def foo(self): pass
Employee.foo = foo
```

as well as assigning to a particular instance. (EDIT: added `self` parameter)

Answer (score 20):

Try with `lambda`:

```
john.greet = lambda : print( 'hello world!' )
```

The you'll be able to do:

```
john.greet()
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks *Thomas K* for the note - this works on `Python 3.2` and not for Python2, where `print` appeared to be `statement`. But this will work for `lambda`s, without *statements* (right? Sorry, I know only `python3.2` (: )

Comment: This doesn't actually work: lambdas can't contain statements.

Comment: @katrielalex - Works perfect on my python 3.2 (with added parentheses for `print`, of course). What statemets?

Comment: @Kirii: In Python 2, `print` is a statement. You're adding brackets because in Python 3, it became a function.

Comment: @Thomas K - ah, thanks! I didn't know, that `print` is statement in Python2.

Comment: Since the OP wanted to dynamically define a function, perhaps the `print` example wasn't the best. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "named tuples" from the `collection` standard module. Named tuples work like "ordinary" tuples but the elements have names and you can access the elements using the "dot syntax". From the [collection docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=named%20tuple#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> # Basic example
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
>>> p[0] + p[1]             # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22)
33
>>> x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
>>> x, y
(11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y               # fields also accessible by name
33
>>> p                       # readable __repr__ with a name=value style
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AttrDict

```
>>> from attrdict import AttrDict
>>> my_object = AttrDict()
>>> my_object.my_attribute = 'blah'
>>> print my_object.my_attribute
blah
>>>
```

Install attrdict from PyPI:

```
pip install attrdict
```

It's useful in other situations too - like when you need attribute access to dict keys.

Comment: sure, more dependencies for the God of Dependencies