# Is it possible to initialize a instance variable when there is no variable in the class?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create and initialize an instance variable after initializing a class?

```
class Point:
    def move(self):
        print("Move")
    def draw(self):
        print("Draw")

point1 = Point()
point1.x = 10
point1.y = 20
print("X: " + point1.x)
print("Y: " + point1.y)
```

I am beginner to Python and it's a little concept that I cannot get at this time.

Comment: Does the code you posted do what you expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new member variables to python objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043524/adding-new-member-variables-to-python-objects)

Comment: @khelwood Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is! From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends): *"Sometimes it is useful to have a data type similar to the Pascal “record” or C “struct”, bundling together a few named data items. An empty class definition will do nicely."*

Python lets you add elements to your defined classes after you've defined them. Your code (with a slight modification; as written, you need a comma instead of a plus in your print statements) will compile and run without issue. In fact, here's your code [running online.](https://repl.it/repls/GrowingAlarmingCoordinates) Looks good to me!

That's not all, though. Python classes are more or less ["fancy dict wrappers"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6204100/7431860), which is to say, you can store all sorts of things in them after they're instantiated. In fact, you can even define functions and store them in the class. Python's *really* flexible.

Comment: Thanks Nick Reed. Now I understand this.

Comment: @FahadIqbalKhan Very glad to help! Please consider accepting the answer if it properly addresses your question, and good luck with the rest of your code.